# Is there a way to add a drawing component inside video player in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

I was thinking of having a button which calls a drawing component so I can draw on top of the video player component.

```
const VideoPlayer = ({selectedVideo}) => {
    
    return(
        <div className="App">
       <video key = {selectedVideo} width="950" height="500" controls>
         <source 
         key= {selectedVideo}
         src={selectedVideo} 
         type="video/mp4" />
         </video>
   </div>
    );
};

export default VideoPlayer;
```

I was thinking of writing something similar to this:
[I want to draw (using html5 canvas) inside video in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602059/i-want-to-draw-using-html5-canvas-inside-video-in-react) but with the ability to having drawing enabled or disabled with a button press and that it stays within the boundaries of the video player. How do you suggest I go about doing this?

Comment: I don't use ReactJs but you need a Canvas tag of same size as the Video tag. **(1)** You can use `z-index` to position it in a next layer above the video (_eg:_ `myCanvas.style.zIndex = 2;`). **(2)** Have a button whose function (on click) will change a Boolean to true or false (_eg:_ `if ( can_draw == true) { can_draw = false; } else { can_draw = true; }`. **(3)** To show drawings you need the canvas to have transparent pixels (set alpha of every pixel to zero using a For-loop), only set alpha to 255 for the drawn pixels (so they are not transparent).

Comment: I'll try that out, thanks!